# How can I make a file hard to read like the bellow attached file ( image )

Tags: file, security, encryption, encoding, utf

I have some **.sh file**s, this file contains my **ssh and scp** details.
I would **like to encrypt** the ssh files, **upon encryption** It should be able to **execute/run**.

like the background.js ( attachment ) file is encrypted but still executing in the browser

[image]

Comment: What you're describing is not really encryption in a reasonable way. If the `.sh` file itself contains the information necessary to execute your code, then it also needs to contain the information to decrypt the code and can easily be manipulated into doing decrypt-and-save-to-file instead of decrypt-and-run. In other words: this is a very thin layer of obfuscation that provides no real security against anyone with a modicum of understanding in the technology you're working with.

Comment: Everything *encrypted* must also be *decrypted* eventually in order to be of any use. If it needs to "just run", then that decryption can't really hide much; you probably do not want to have to type in the decryption key every time you run it, right? As such, where the key is "hidden" and whether that makes any sense in practice is the real issue…

Answer (score 2):

**Background:**
There is a difference between **obfuscation** and **encryption**.

Obfuscation hides the data or makes it hard to read, but it is still theoretically possible to reverse this and get back the original source data.

Encryption actually uses cryptography to make it near-impossible to decrypt without a key.

I believe the image I'm looking at above is "obfuscated" and not "encrypted" based on the details that you've provided.

**Answer:**
If you're running this file on a machine and not in a browser, I'd recommend looking at compiling it into an executable which will compile it into bytecode. This will likely accomplish your original intent of hiding the source. [Nexe](https://github.com/nexe/nexe) is one tool for NodeJS that can do this.

If you're running this in the browser, then you can only really obfuscate it. [Terser](https://github.com/terser/terser) is a library for this in NodeJS

And lastly, a common pattern for hiding ssh details is to put them into environment variables and have a script reference the environment variables rather than actually putting the credentials in the code.
In JS, that would be `process.env.PASSWORD`

Comment: I can put into environment variables, but I don't want any other developer to see the data inside the .sh files

Comment: yea if you put the password into the environment variables, then you wouldn't commit the separate password files into the repository

Comment: Also, .sh files are typically for shell executable files. If you're just putting a username/password into a file, then take a look at this https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv